# How to buld a new docking bar in QT

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am trying to replace the Fluxbox dockbar at the bottom in my RHEL environment.  I would like to program it in C++ with QT.

Can someone please tell me how I can get started?  Is there any example code?  Where can I get info to help me along?

Thanks so much.

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about studying existing code like the [KoolDock](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=12097) (which is for KDE, and uses QT) or [Daisy](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Daisy?content=102077). Grab its source code and start hacking it up.  Starting from scratch is not kosher. Google, download, build. Or just `apt-cache search` if you're a debian-like distro, and use whatever package-source-RPM search tools exist on RHEL, for RedHat.

Obviously you would need to modify it to work properly in a non-KDE context.

Comment: Thanks Warren, but both of those have the MAC look.  I need a windows look.

Comment: There's tonnes of docks in the KDE look website. Surely one of them has a windows look.